# Google Maps API Custom Pop-Up

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am messing around with the Google Maps API and I can't seem to figure out how to add a pop-up within the map that comes up with info after someone clicks on the custom map icon I've added. The code I am using is below and an example is on littlemarketbrasserie.com

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 15,
          panControl: false,
          mapTypeControl: false,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.89924, -87.62756),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
                                      mapOptions);

        var image = 'img/lm-logo-maps1.png';
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.89924, -87.62756);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            icon: image,
        });

        var styles = [
                  {
                    stylers: [
                      { hue: "#ff9f67" },
                      { saturation: -20 },
                      { gamma: 1.50 }
                    ]
                  },{
                    featureType: "road",
                    elementType: "geometry",
                    stylers: [
                      { lightness: 100 },
                      { visibility: "simplified" }
                    ]
                  },{
                    featureType: "road",
                    elementType: "labels.text.stroke",
                    stylers: [
                      { visibility: "off" }
                    ]
                  },

                  {
                    featureType: "water",
                    elementType: "geometry.fill",
                    stylers: [
                        { visibility: "on" },
                        { color: "#ffa066" },
                        { lightness: 80 }
                    ]
                    }
                ];

                map.setOptions({styles: styles});
      }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are talking about `infowindow` then you can use inside your `initialize` function

```
var popup=new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "Hello"
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(e) {
    // you can use event object as 'e' here
    popup.open(map, this);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fn55p/5/).

Also if you want to add a custom styled `infowindow` then you can take a look at [this](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.5/docs/examples.html) and [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/fn55p/6/) using jQuery dialog.